# Is it possible to exclude selection of FK's on SELECT * JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have 2 tables, T1 and T2, with 1 `PK` each. And T2's `PK` is actually an `FK` pointing out the `PK` of T1 like so;

`T1: {PK1, Foo, Bar}`

`T2: {PK2, Baz} with foreign key {PK2 -> T1.PK1}`

Following MySQL query will select all the columns from both table;

```sql
SELECT * FROM T1 JOIN T2;
```

```
| PK1 | PK2 | Foo | Bar | Baz |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
```

However in our case PK1 and PK2 contain identical values with different names. Is there a way to alter our SQL to exclude identical `FK` column(s) **WITHOUT** requiring to write every column name manually?

Comment: Nope; `SELECT *` is generally considered poor practice in anything but testing and direct analysis queries written on the fly. If they were the same name, MySQL does have an alternative to ON called USING that does have this affect. Also, having a child whose PK is nothing more than the parent's PK raises the question of why the tables are even separate to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this if the keys have the same name.  In that case, you can use `USING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 JOIN
     T2
     USING (t1_id);
```

I'm not a big fan of `select *` except in ad-hoc code.  But this can be convenient.